are there ways to reflect views from database with SQLALCHEMY
I am developing a website with Flask, I am not using flask-sqlalchemy because I had problem when I tried to connect and use two databases. I solve using SqlAlchemy directly but here is a question, how can I mirror sql views already created, I don't want to create one because there is, if there is no ways instead I use raw SQL?
example with table but I want to do it with view:

from ...database import metadata_revroe

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import VARCHAR


transport_cash_model = Table(
    "Transporte_Efectivo",
    metadata_revroe,
    Column("ID_LOG", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("tipo_INSTITUCION", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("ID_INSTITUCION", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("NOMBRE_INSTITUCION", VARCHAR(150)),
    Column("RegionOr", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("LocalidadOr", VARCHAR(150)),
    Column("CalleOr", VARCHAR(150)),
    Column("NumeroOr", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("DeptoOfOr", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("TelefonoOr", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("RegionDest", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("LocalidadDest", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("CalleDest", VARCHAR(150)),
    Column("NumeroDest", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("DeptoOfDest", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("TelefonoDest", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("CodigoMonedaTransportada", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Monto", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Fecha", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("NumeroIdentificacion", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("TipoDocumento", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("NombreRaZonSocial", VARCHAR(300)),
    Column("ApellidoPaterno", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("ApellidoMaterno", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Nacionalidad", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Habitualidad", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Pais", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("RegionEstado", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("ComunaCiudad", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Calle", VARCHAR(150)),
    Column("Num", VARCHAR(150)),
    Column("DeptoOf", VARCHAR(50)),
    Column("Telefono", VARCHAR(50))
)



What happens if you do the same thing and simply use the name of the view as the "table name" (first argument)?
